# HQL checking if object contains all element s of requested set

Tags: java, spring, jpa, hql, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities. For example, posts and tags to it. 
I have to write a method that will take only posts, which have all of tags, mentioned in query.

I tried

```
@Query("select distinct p from posts p join p.tags t where t in ?1")
Page<Post> findDistinctByTagsIn(Set<Tag> tagSet, Pageable pageable);
```

However it takes Post if at least one of its tags included in tagSet.

How can I solve this using only HQL and JPA Repositories?

UPD:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "posts_tags", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "post_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")})
public Set<Tag> getTags() {
    return tags;
}
```

Comment: How are posts and tags linked to each other in the data model? We need to know the relevant parts of these entities or underlying tables.

Comment: @MickMnemonic, Tags and posts are lmany-to-many linked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to you `Tag` class next `ManyToOne` relation:

```
@Entity
public class Tag{
    ...

    private Post post;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "posts_tags",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "post_id")})
    public Post getPost(){
        return post;
    }

    ...
}
```

Let's try to build query.

We don't need posts that have tags that are out of our list of tags. We will select them with next query:

```
select t.post from Tag t where t not in (:tagSet) and t.post is not null
```

And we don't need posts, that have not any tags at all. Let's select them as well:

```
select p from Post p where p.tags is empty
```

Now let's join our queries together:

```
select p from Post p where 
p not in (select t.post from Tag t where t not in (:tagSet) and t.post is not null) 
and p not in (select p2 from Post p2 where p2.tags is empty)
```

And you can use named parameter to bind this query:

```
Page<Post> findDistinctByTagsIn(@Param("tagSet") Set<Tag> tagSet, Pageable pageable);
```